# Why does my request to consent admin permissions ask all permissions?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I am going to consent only specific admin permissions in graph api.

But it requests all tenant permissions.

Current logic is

1. Get delegated token by authorization.

   [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={CLIENT_ID}&response_type=token&redirect_uri={LOGIN_REDIRECT_URI}&response_mode=form_post&scope=offline_access](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BTENANT_ID%7D/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=%7BCLIENT_ID%7D&response_type=token&redirect_uri=%7BLOGIN_REDIRECT_URI%7D&response_mode=form_post&scope=offline_access) https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
2. Prompt admin consent

   [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/adminconsent?client_id={CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=http://localhost/team-members/getAppToken&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/calendars.readwrite](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BTENANT_ID%7D/adminconsent?client_id=%7BCLIENT_ID%7D&redirect_uri=http://localhost/team-members/getAppToken&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/calendars.readwrite)
3. Get application token

   [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token?scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/calendars.readwrite](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BTENANT_ID%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token?scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/calendars.readwrite)

In this logic, admin consent is always asked all permissions in 2), but I want to ask only the permission `Calendars.ReadWrite`.

[image]

How to ask to consent for a specific permissions?

Comment: What is your permission type? Is it application permissions or delegated permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to your permission type. If your permission is a **delegated permission**, you can dynamically agree to a specific delegated permission on the administrator consent page: `scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/calendars.readwrite`.

If your permissions are **application permissions**, you can only request the static `/.default` scope, which will require the administrator to consent to all permissions in the tenant: `scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`.

See the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-admin-consent#request-the-permissions-from-a-directory-admin), there are detailed instructions:

> At this point, Azure AD requires a tenant administrator to sign in to
> complete the request. The administrator is asked to approve all the
> permissions that you have requested in the `scope` parameter. If you've
> used a static (`/.default`) value, it will function like the v1.0 admin
> consent endpoint and request consent for all scopes found in the
> required permissions (both user and app). In order to request app
> permissions, you must use the `/.default` value. If you don't want
> admins to see a given permission in the admin consent screen all the
> time when you use `/.default`, the best practice is to not put the
> permission in the required permissions section. Instead you can use
> dynamic consent to add the permissions you want to be in the consent
> screen at run time, rather than using `/.default`.

Comment: Thanks for your answering to my question, then I can't request the specific permissions for application permission type, right?

Comment: @hotcakedev  Yes!

Comment: Can you help to to solve this issue as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67293271/deleting-an-event-returns-success-but-not-worked-actually?noredirect=1#comment118946486_67293271

Answer (score 0):

If you login to Azure portal and find your application

https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade/RegisteredApps

Click on API Permissions tab

[image]

You will see all configured permissions for Microsoft Graph API.

Ensure that there is only `Calendars.ReadWrite` by removing all redundant permissions.

Comment: Lol, Thanks, you mean scope won't work in adminconsent uri?

Comment: As you know, regarding documentation, it says `scope=` will prompt the scopes, and `scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` will prompt all permissions in the tenant, right?