# Implementing Incremental consent when using both application and delegated permissions

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, azure-app-registration, microsoft-oauth

I have an application permission like `TeamsAppInstallation.ReadWriteSelfForUser.All`.
I also have some delegated permissions. 
 
I want an admin to allow a small set of permissions including the `TeamsAppInstallation.ReadWriteSelfForUser.All` and few delegated permissions during the initial installation phase of an app. 
Later on, the admin can increment and allow all the permissions.

Using the `/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?` endpoint by adding a `scope` param isn't supported for application permissions.

Using the `/common/adminconsent?` is not incremental, as it asks the admin to authorise all application and all delegated permissions.

How can incremental consent be achieved for the admin by allowing app permissions + some delegated permissions? Is there a different/better approach for this?

Referance: [Why does my request to consent admin permissions ask all permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908864/why-does-my-request-to-consent-admin-permissions-ask-all-permissions)